# What is a word for someone who enjoys discussions?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

Someone who enjoys discussions could be described as?

Comment: There are plenty of *insults* for people who like to argue, "argumentative", "contentious" and others. If you want to specify polite and constructive discussions I don't have an answer yet.  Could you provide a sample sentence with a blank where the word would go? It would provide useful context.

Comment: policy discussions? gossipy discussions? just likes to talk? can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: It's for a translation of the German compound noun Diskussionsfreudigkeit.

Comment: Sr0r, that is not what has been requested. This is not a translation website.

Comment: @Edwin I am not requesting a translation, i merely gave the specific background of my query.

Comment: @Sr0r, if you could expound on the qualities you expect this word to fulfill, you might help weed out answers that are entirely off base.  For example, is this a positive trait or a negative one?

Comment: But that might have been 'I read it in a comic once, I think'. Now three people have asked for **helpful** context, which as per site rules should be in English. I've answered, guessing that you didn't want an answer marked for bloody-mindedness (eg wrangler) or professionalism (eg polemicist). But I was guessing.

Comment: Could you please state if you are looking for a term that has positive or negative connotations. Could you give a little more information about this person, an example of their behaviour. This will mean that answers will be more specific, pertinent, and "correct".

Answer (score 3):

A **conversationalist**:

> conversationalist n
>
> 1. a person who enjoys or excels in conversation

[ [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conversationalist)]

> {discussion  n.
>
> 1. Consideration of a subject by a group; an earnest conversation.

[ [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discussion)] }

Answer (score 3):

*This answer takes into consideration the comments posted along with the question.*

If my understanding is correct, the German word *"Diskussionsfreudigkeit"* means having a *propensity to debate* or *keen to debate*.

Hence, maybe you're looking for *"debater"*.

### debater

a person who engages in debate

> **debate**
>
> - a discussion between people in which they express different opinions about something
>    ~ [Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/debate)
> - to engage in argument or discussion / to dispute or disagree about
>    ~ [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/debater)

Comment: I voted for *Debater* that I prefer to **Polemicist** that has no pleasure connotation.

Answer (score 1):

[Argumentative](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/argumentative):

> - fond of or given to argument; *disputatious.*
>
>   - *an argumentative employee*

(AHD)

Comment: These all have negative connotations.  So someone can't enjoy a discussion without being perceived negatively? (she asked in an argumentative tone! lol!)  The German word she is trying to reproduce in English doesn't have the negative cast that these words do, FWIW.

Comment: @kristina - FYI - the German term was posted after my answer. The question was about someone who likes discussions ( which does not imply anything necessarily  positive).

Comment: "I like to discuss matters over a cup of coffee" and "We discussed over coffee" is not the same as *arguing*. In Italian *discutere* can have positive and negative connotations. In English the term, discuss,  is rarely seen as being negative. A person who enjoys quarrelling is *argumentative*. A person who enjoys discussing is closer to being *talkative*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - ( no discussion please)  Discuss : ***consider or examine by argument***. 
to discuss the proposed law on taxes. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discuss

Comment: But when you discuss something you don't normally raise your voice, there is no anger involved. And an argument also means a topic. [Can you not see how my example sentence "discuss over coffee" is more positive and fits better than "argue"?]